# How to fix "Table <table_name>" does not exist exception after adding table name in @Table annotation in spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I am trying to connect my MySql server to my springboot project. I have a table called product_cateogories which i am trying to connect with entity productCategory like this:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;  
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity(name = "product_categories")
@Table(name = "product_categories", schema =<schema>)
public class ProductCategory implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "category_id")
private long categoryId;

@Column(name = "category_name", nullable = false)
private String categoryName;

@Column(name = "category_parent_id")
private long categoryParentId;

@Column(name = "category_level")
private int categoryLevel;
@Column(name = "category_status")
private int categoryStatus;
```

}

and repo interface

```
@Repository(value = "productrepo")
public interface ProductCategoryRepository extends 
JpaRepository<ProductCategory, Long> {
void deleteByCategoryId(long categoryId);
}
```

my DBConfig

import javax.sql.DataSource;

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import 
 org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;  
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import 
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import 
  org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = 
"com.b2bdaddy.adminproject.repository")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.b2bdaddy.adminproject.entities"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DBConfig {

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.dbb2bdaddy")
public DataSource createProductCategoryServiceDataBase() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

 }
```

**The project is starting fine without any problem but i get this following error whenever i try to access data.**

```
    java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table '<schema>.product_category' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~ 
    [mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) 
    ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at
```

Also this error as well.

```
   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException 
(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
  Bad SQL grammar [SELECT product_category.category_id AS category_id, 
  product_category.category_name AS category_name, 
  product_category.category_parent_id AS category_parent_id, 
  product_category.category_level AS category_level, 
  product_category.category_status AS category_status FROM  
  product_category]; 
  nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 
  '<schema>.product_category' doesn't exist
```

Even though i have added @Entity and @Table with the table name, i still get product_category instead of product_categories.

Create statement of the table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `product_categories` (
`category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`category_name` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
`category_parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`category_level` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
`category_status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE 
 CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`),
  KEY `category_Status_fk_idx` (`category_status`),
   CONSTRAINT `category_status_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`category_status`) 
   REFERENCES 
   `status` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
   COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: Is your schema really called `<schema>`, or is it a spring-boot thing?

Comment: I changed the name to that just now for stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

you should check case sensitivity in column names on Database

Comment: I added the table create statement as well. I dont have any issues with that.

Comment: maybe you should use `Integer` instead of `int`. and `long` to `Long`

Comment: I dont think that is the issue, because it picks the wrong table 'product_category' instead of 'product_categories'.

Comment: where is your query? can you add it here?

Comment: SELECT product_category.category_id AS category_id, 
  product_category.category_name AS category_name, 
  product_category.category_parent_id AS category_parent_id, 
  product_category.category_level AS category_level, 
  product_category.category_status AS category_status FROM  
  product_category This is what is called when i call.

Comment: your table name is not `product_category`. you can try this: `product_categories`

Comment: Yes, that is true but think about the entity, the entity is one single product category not list of categories. So, thats why i named it product_category and i have mentioned the '@Table' and '@Entity' annotation to correct that.

Comment: you shouldn't give both of them that name. `@Entity(name = <"new_name">)`. After using this anotation, you should call it by name. try it: `@Entity(name = "product_category")`

Comment: or `@Table(name = "product_category")` i am not sure, Try these. I wonder.